# Check if two or more values exist in an array

Tags: ruby

I get this response in Ruby:

```
 puts templateid --> ["10001", "10404"]
```

The first one should be #{mstmplid} and the second one should be #{ostmplid}. I want to check if this array contains these two values with the following function:

```
if templateid.all? { |x| ["#{mstmplid}", "#{ostmplid}"].include?(x) }
  puts "OK"
end
```

Unfortunatelyy templateid.all? is the same with templateid.any? so it will check if any of the specified values are in the array. How can I check if both values are there?

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Do you really just _"want to check if this array contains these two values"_? Is the element order important or the number of elements?

Comment: `puts` usually prints each element on a new line.

Comment: How about `["10001", "10404"] == ["#{mstmplid}", "#{ostmplid}"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this two arrays always have just 2 elements, you can check it just by:

```
templateid.sort == [mstmplid, ostmplid].map(&:to_s).sort
```

if you just want to check if `mstmplid, ostmplid` included in `templateid` you should write like this:

```
[mstmplid, ostmplid].map(&:to_s).all? { |x| templateid.include? x }
```